# Cricket Probability Question AMC8 2022

Tags: probability

I have been preparing for the next AMC$8$ and AMC$10$ in the US, and my coaching teacher gave me some questions for practice. I have an AMC8 $2022$ Question given to me by that teacher that I've been trying to do for a while, but cannot seem to solve:

A cricket randomly hops between $4$ leaves, on each turn hopping to one of the other 3 leaves with equal probability. After $4$ hops, what is the probability that the cricket has returned to the leaf where it started?

Could anyone please help? Thank you!

Note: The teacher found the problem at this link and gave it to me: https://ivyleaguecenter.files.wordpress.com/2022/01/2022-amc-8-problems-and-answers.pdf

Comment: Where are you stuck? Can you solve it if the number of hops is smaller?

Comment: I mean if it only hops once, the probability is zero???

Comment: Right. How about 2 hops? Try to keep going.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a_t$ be the position of the cricket after $t$ hops. We label the four leaves by $1, 2, 3, 4$ and assume $a_0=1$. If $a_3=1$, it cannot stay there at $t=4$. If $a_3\not=1$, there is always the probability $\frac{1}{3}$ for the cricket to hop back to $1$ in the next. So,

$$P(a_4=1)=P(a_3\not=1)\cdot \frac{1}{3} = (1-P(a_3=1))\cdot \frac{1}{3}$$

For $a_3=1$ to hold, $a_1$ to $a_2$ must be a hop among the leaves $2, 3, 4$, whose probability is $\frac{2}{3}$ no matter what $a_1\not=1$ is. And for $a_2\in\{2,3,4\}$ to transit to $a_3=1$, the probability is again $\frac{1}{3}$. Thus,

$$P(a_3=1)=\frac{2}{3}\cdot\frac{1}{3}=\frac{2}{9}$$

Hence $$P(a_4=1)=\frac{7}{27}$$